# Angular fails to fetch CSS file on navigation to nested route

Tags: css, angular

When directly navigating to a child component in prod mode (ng serve --prod) it fails to load the CSS file, trying to fetch it from a nested path. For instance, navigating to "localhost:4200/doc/" the CSS Request URL is:

> localhost:4200/doc/styles.6eab038f040a1c7c7ed6.css.

The error that is given:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/doc/styles.6eab038f040a1c7c7ed6.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

When accessing the root (localhost:4200) the CSS is loaded correctly. If you then navigate to the child component through the app itself, the problem does not occur.

It only occurs in prod mode, not on the development server. Changed nothing to the regular settings regarding styles.css, it is situated in the default folder.

```
          "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

Anyone has any idea how this problem could be caused?

**Edit**

Found out that the problem lies in navigating to nested routes (helped by the reply of *mikegross*).

On a route without a nested parameter the problem does not occur, but on a route with a nested parameter (for instance 'doc/:id') it does.

Router module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: "full"},
  { path: 'list', component: ListComponent},
  { path: 'doc/:id', component: DocumentComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: ''},
];

@NgModule({ 
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Update (feb. 28)**

Since it was still a small project I generated a new angular project, installed same dependencies and literally copy pasted the code.

Although I have no idea why, in the new project the problem does not occur. The only difference lies in a minor version bump (ng 9.0 to 9.1).

Comment: what's your <base href="/"> tag in index.html?

Comment: <base href="/">

Comment: I remember I had this once.. It has to do with your router module, but I can't remember exactly what it was.

Comment: I found something peculiar, maybe it rings a bell:

On a route without a nested parameter (for instance: 'about') the problem does not occur, but on a route with a nested parameter (for instance 'doc/:id') it does. 

For fetching the CSS, does it only cut out the last segment of the path (the ':id'), so that the '/doc' remains?

Comment: It's strange, are you by any chance importing the css with an absolute path in teh component or with a relative path? Even this way, the build should work perfectly.. Do you have any custom build configuration?

Comment: No, I the css importing from the component was per default, as was the build configuration. I have solved the problem by copy-pasting the code into a new project, which was doable because it was still a small project. Do not know why it works now, only difference between the new and old project is a minor version bump (ng 9 to 9.1).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but I got around this by using query parameters instead of route parameters. example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: "full"},
  { path: 'list', component: ListComponent},
  { path: 'doc', component: DocumentComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: ''},
];
```

(I removed the :id from "doc/:id")

Navigate to the route:

```
route this._router.navigate(['/doc'],{queryParams: {id: id}});
```

Then retrieve the query parameter:

```
this._activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('id');
```

Comment: sadly it did not work for me, the first time I go into the url its all normal, but after a refresh, the same error happened:

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Coming late to the party. I had the same error with React in 2022.

Initially, I declared the CSS file with a relative path, as follows:

```
<link rel="preload" href="./style/Avenir-Light.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

After changing it to an absolute path, it worked

```
<link rel="preload" href="/style/Avenir-Light.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

Hope it helps future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and it was resolved by correcting the base-href value, but within the angular.json file rather than the index.html file.

Within angular.json, I changed:

`baseHref: "."`

to:

`baseHref: "/"`

and the issue was resolved.